# A more efficient way of clipping the values in arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, broadcast

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

MIN = -3
MAX = 3

def bound(array):
    return np.array([(0 if v == 0 else (MIN if v < 0 else 1)) for v in array]),\
           np.array([(0 if v == 0 else (-1 if v < 0 else MAX)) for v in array])

print(bound(np.array(range(MIN, MAX + 1))))
```

which returns:

```
(array([-3, -3, -3,  0,  1,  1,  1]), array([-1, -1, -1,  0,  3,  3,  3]))
```

My actual array is much bigger than this but is made up of integers ranging from MIN to MAX (in this case -3 to 3).

MIN and MAX are not to be considered symmetric to 0 but values of 0 should be maintained.

Is there a more efficient/faster (cpu time) way of doing the same?
Time comparisons are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `np.select`:

```
def bound2(arr):
    pos_neg = arr>0, arr<0
    return (
        np.select(pos_neg, (1,MIN),0),
        np.select(pos_neg, (MAX,-1),0)
    )
```

Test time:

```
# sample data
arr = np.random.randint(-10,10,1000)

%%timeit -n 100
bound(arr)
# 858 µs ± 28.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
bound2(arr)
# 59.9 µs ± 4.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [np.where](https://thispointer.com/numpy-where-tutorial-examples-python/)

```
def bound_where(array):
  return np.where(array==0, 0, np.where(array<0, MIN, 1)), \
           np.where(array==0, 0, np.where(array<0, -1, MAX))
```

Comparison with other methods

**Test**

Methods

1. Posted Method
2. Select method (bound2 from @QuangHoang answer)
3. Where Method (current answer)

*Test Code*

```
arr = np.random.randint(-10,10,1000)
count = 1000
print(f'Posted method: {timeit(lambda:bound(arr), number=count):.4f}')
print(f'Select method: {timeit(lambda:bound2(arr), number=count):.4f}')
print(f'Where mehtod: {timeit(lambda:bound_where(arr), number=count):.4f}')
```

**Results (seconds)**

```
Posted method: 6.1951
Select method: 0.3959
Where method: 0.1466
```

Where method fastest overall